# SpringBootTest/WebMvcTest not invoking validator on request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test a controller such that it triggers validation on the request body object based on the validators that I have defined on the object. Below are the relevant classes. 
If you notice my test method I am expecting bad request based on the validator defined, but for some reason it directly tries to execute the service, which was not expected and therefore I don't have any mock defined for the service and hence, I get a NullPointerException since the service object is null as it is mocked.
I tried replacing WebMvcTest to SpringBootTest based on some suggestions that I googled and stackoverflowed, but nothing helped. What could be the possible reason?

**Request Object**

```
@Validated
public class RequestBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -8976713543478074839L;

   @NotNull
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
   private String name;

   @NotEmpty
   private List<Long> statusIds;

   // getters and setters

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

   @Autowired
   private SomeService service;

   @PostMapping(value = "/resources", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public List<VerDealProductBean> fetchResources(
        @Valid @RequestBody RequestBean request)
        throws SomeException {
    return service.doSomething(request);
}
```

**Controller Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeControllerTest {

   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @MockBean
   private SomeService service;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(SomeController.class)
            .build();
   }

   @Test
   public void testFetchResourcesWithNoInput() throws Exception {
       String request = "{\"id\": null}";
       mockMvc.perform(post("/resources")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .content(request))
                .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
   }
```

}

Comment: Why do you have @Validated annotation on the top of your bean?

Comment: I actually had group validation enabled, so the actual attributes are divided in groups in which they would be validated as part of that group only

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you lack a package javax.el

http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
</dependency>
```